# How Do I update record from this JSON object in Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm getting this json in LWC js file as:

```
{"a013H000000hsHVQAY":"val1","a013H000000hsHWQAY":"val2","a013H000000hsHYQAY":"val3"}
```

These Ids are one of the Custom object and we have one custom field in this object which needs to be updated from these val1, val2,val3
I'm getting these values from change handler of this:

```
<lightning-input type="text" access-key={wrap.Id} onchange={handleChange} value={wrap.myCustomField__c}>
```

And then in js getting as:

```
this.obj[event.target.accessKey] = event.target.value;
```

Input field is in `template for:each` I'm new to apex, little help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just use LDS `updateRecord`?

Comment: But that requires this format::     let record = {
        fields: {
            Id: this.recordId,
            Name: this.name,
            AnnualRevenue:this.annualrev ,
            Fax:this.fax ,
            Phone:this.phone,
        },
    };
    updateRecord(record)

Comment: Yeah, so format your object like that?

Comment: Yup formatted that in correct format now i got it what wanted. Thanks